# Add item in listview in Form1 from textbox in Form2 C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, listview

I have 2 forms, let's say Form1 and Form2.

In **Form1** there is a **button**, that shows Form2 when it's pressed, and a **ListView**.

In **Form2** there is a **textbox** and a **button**. When the button is pressed, I want the text from the textbox to be added as an item in ListView in Form1.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(textBox1.Text);
     Form1.listView1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

I get error

> "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'project.Form1.listView1'

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to instantiate Form1 to be able to add items to the ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(textBox1.Text);
     Form1 f1 = new Form();
     f1.listView1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: This works, but I have to close each form every time and open a new one. I was wondering if there is a way to create an item in ListView in the existing Form1. Maybe I should take a look at using databases.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Form2` constructor get an instance of `Form1` and use that to access the listbox.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of breaking the OOP structure you should think about using the PropertyChangedEvent. As soon as you create an instance of Form2 bind to that event that raises in textview change.

Edit: writing via phone so samples are hard to create. Take a look at this link for some hints. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventhandler.aspx